# How to share a workspace between 2 Jenkins pipelines?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have 2 pipeline jobs where job1 triggers job2. I want job2 to run in the same build node and workspace as job1. I've done the following

```
job1:
node("linux-ubuntu") {
    echo "Node: $env.NODE_NAME"
    ws {
        "$env.WORKSPACE/test"
    }
    build job: "Utilities/Playground/pass-node-job2",
          parameters: [
              string(name: "BUILD_NODE", value: env.NODE_NAME),
              string(name: "WSPACE", value: "$env.WORKSPACE/test")
          ],
          wait: true
}

job2:
properties([
  parameters([
    string(name: 'BUILD_NODE', defaultValue: "linux-ubuntu", description: 'If this job is triggered by another job, it will passed in its build node.'),
    string(name: "WSPACE", defaultValue: env.WORKSPACE, description: "Workspace")
  ])
])

node(env.BUILD_NODE) {
    sh "echo node: $env.BUILD_NODE"
    sh "echo wspace: $env.WSPACE"
    dir(env.WSPACE) {
        sh "pwd && ls"
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I'm aware of the [shared workspace plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/shared-workspace/), but I don't think it supports pipelines.

**Edit**
I know this is a simplified use case. To provide a context, I want to be able to still run job2 separately.

For my case, I use a Git submodule. I have several `job2's` dedicated to build each child module, and have `job1` to clone the Git submodule repo. So when `job1` clones the repo, it'll do it on a certain build node and workspace inside that build node. Now when it triggers `job2` to build the child module, I **need** `job2` to run in the same build node and workspace where `job1` cloned the Git submodule.

But I don't need to run `job1` every time, and still want to be able to run `job2` **any time**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you try to avoid cloning the repo multiple times. If it takes too much time you could make the trick and then just clone the repo in all your job2 instances instead of tampering with workspace:

- create bare git repo on the agent machine - this will be your local intermediate repo
- clone original repo into intermediate repo
- modify job2 to:

  - update intermediate repo so that it is up-to-date with original - this is fast
  - clone from intermediate repo - this is fast too because you are on the same machine

I am not sure about your motivation to do the task specifically by using shared workspace, so I may be wrong with the above suggestion. This is however an example of action in case of concrete problem.
For sure you should understand what is your desired outcome of the task. Workspace as the name says is meant to be tightly coupled with its job and passing it around doesn't seem to be great idea - just use `wait:false` and everything will fall apart when job1 restarts before job2 ends.

**Edit1:**
I am adding concept diagram here for the situation git submodules exist in git repo 1:
[image: concept of intermediate repository]

Comment: Thanks.  Yes I want to avoid cloning the repo multiple times since that takes too long for a Git submodule. I don't follow your "intermediate repo" nomenclature so maybe reword your answer with concrete Git commands? Remember, I have several agents. And yes I'm not 100% enamored with my approach; hence, I asked if there's a better way.

Comment: Well, it is just to create intermediate repo and use it in the pipeline. It is technically bare repo so it doesn't have working tree:

Comment: But how do I create a bare Git submodule that has several child modules? IDK if that's what you're suggesting, it's unclear. My example only shows one `job2` for simplicity, but I may need `job1` to trigger **several** `job2`s

Comment: Sorry, I was editing and 5 minutes passed... 
1* manually clone existing repo on machine with Jenkins agent: `git clone --bare <git-repo-ref>` 
2* add stage into your pipeline to update bare repo each time pipeline starts (you need to change to appropriate dir): `git fetch <git-repo-ref> master:master` 
3* use bare repo to clone from in the pipeline: `git clone <bare-git-repo-ref>`

Comment: You do not need to use `job1` at all. You just work with bare repo in all of your `job2` instances, unless you have yet another problem on your plate.

Comment: My `job1` is my orchestrator. If a user want's to build `feature/proj-123-fix-stuff` he/she runs `job1` which then orchestrates all the `job2`s that are affected by that feature. Or a user can just choose to run one `job2` if he/she is just working on that module.  Not all `job2`s necessarily have that feature brtanch. I simplified my post to make it more fundamental.

Comment: Ok, so `job2` should just clone local (bare) repo everytime it starts. As I say it should be fast. Then it can use any specific module it needs. If for some reason `job1` also needs repo access it can also clone local repo. Every job uses its own workspace then. You could make some sample jobs to measure performance of this solution and see if this is acceptable.

Comment: I followed your 3 steps. I needed 3 more steps to actually get the code locally. 4* `cd <git-repo-ref-local-copy>` 5* `git submodule init` 6* `git submodule update --remote <child-module>`. So if I have 20 child modules for a feature, I'll have to repeat at least my steps #5 and #6 for each child-module running in `job2`? I want to avoid "getting code locally" multiple times if possible, but in a more elegant way than I've done it.

Comment: Ok, it seems you have the problem on your plate. How many repositories are you cloning then? If you consider all your jobs - how many will it be (it doesn't matter if parent repository or submodule one).

Comment: It depends on the feature. I may have a small feature that spans 1-3 microservices, or a mega feature that spans 10+, and more UI code (also in its own repo). Now you understand why I simplified my post because not everyone understands Git submodules.

Comment: I would still try local repo concept but in more automated way, so all these steps should be part of your pipeline: step1-create local bare repo if it doesn't exist (multiple repos if required), step2-update them, step3-clone them to the workspace. I am not sure you should be creating git submodule at all - you just need data from various repositories in your workspace if I understand correctly. So instead of `git submodule init` you could just create separate local repo cloning `<child-module>` (step1). You should check with 2-3 repos if this concept pays off in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

If it is feasible, instead of the job  triggering the job 2, since you seem to know about scripted pipelines what you can do is build the pipeline and have the job 1 as your first stage in your pipeline and the job 2 as the second stage of your pipeline. This way, you can write something like this :

```
node('BUILD_NODE'){
    ws('absolute_path'){
        stage(stage1){
            stage stuff 1
        }
        stage(stage2){
            stage stuff 2
        }
    }
}
```

In case this wouldn't work for you, can you provide details about the context (Might be the necessity to launch the job 2 directly and not dependently on job 1)

**EDIT**: For what I know, you are doing it the only way it can be done.

Comment: Thanks, I will update my OP and provide a context.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option called `customWorkspace`

```
agent {
    node {
        label 'my-defined-label'
        customWorkspace '/some/other/path'
    }
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/)

Comment: I think this is what I'm doing, but with scriptive pipeline for my example.